# Explicit formula for k-central numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, riemann-hypothesis

Given a positive integer  $ n $ and assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let $r_{0}(n)$ denote the smallest non negative integer $r$ such that both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are primes. Let $k_{0}(n)$ denote 'the order of centrality' of $n$ defined as the quantity $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$. If $k_{0}(n)=k$, we'll say that $n$ is $k$-central.

Let $\theta_{k}(x):=\sum_{n\mid k_{0}(n)=k, n\leq x}\log n$. $\theta_{0}$ is simply the classical Chebyshev function $\theta$.

Can one derive an explicit formula for $\theta_{k}(x)$ in terms of the zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function or some other L-function following the method outlined in Riemann's famous groundbreaking memoir stating RH?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: One can also ask about asymptotics on $\theta_k$. Prime number theorem implies that $\theta_0(x)\sim\theta_1(x)\sim x$, but this is far less clear for $k>1$.

Comment: One can expect the sequence  $ (\theta_{k}(x))_{k\geq 0} $  to be decreasing for a given  $ x $ and  $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\theta_{k}(x) $ to equal  $ \log\Gamma(x+1)+O(1) $.